# Fill HTML Form Fields With JSON Object

Tags: html, json, forms

I have a very basic HTML form which I've created locally and also another form, the same one, on a separate local site.

I was wondering if there was a way to fill out the first HTML form and then automatically fill out the second form with the same data.

I have looked into possibly packaging the form data into a JSON object but can't seem to find good guidance as to how to actually do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <title>Form Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Form Test</h1></center>
    <div class="navigation">
        <nav>
            <a href="secondform.html">Second Form Submission</a>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <p>Upon clicking the submit button, the populated fields should send their field data to the Second Form which will then be emailed to someone.</p>

</body>
<div id="message"> </div>
<form name="form_simple" id="form-simple" action="C:/xampp/htdocs/formsubmit/formsubmit.php" method="post" target="_blank">
    Name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="">
    <br> Email:
    <br>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="">
    <br> University:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="university" value="">
    <br> Year In School:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="year" value="">
    <br> Grad Date:
    <br>
    <input type="date" name="graddate" value="">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using php, there's no need to monkey-about with JSON encoding the data. When you hit the submit button, the `formsubmit.php` page is requested.

In it, you can get back all of the data that your form held. You can then use that to populate the fields of this next form.

I imagine you're not yet familiar with the $_POST and $_GET arrays available to each and every php script. Since your method of the above form is `POST`, you can grab the submitted values from the $_POST array.

That is to say, this array will contain elements in an array that is indexed with the *name* of the original form inputs. In your case, these would be found in `$_POST['name']`, `$_POST['email']`, `$_POST['university']`, `$_POST['year']` and `$_POST['graddate']`.

Now's also a good time to mention that you shouldn't include the full *local* path of the script in the action attribute of the form. Simply refer to it relative to the web-server's root folder. In your case, this is `c:/xampp/htdocs` - this equates to an address of `localhost/` in the browser. So, you should change the action to `/formsubmit/formsubmit.php` or to simply `formsubmit.php` if the html shown above and the php file both exist in the same folder.

Something else you may find of use is the `var_dump` function. If you place `var_dump($_POST);` in the `formsubmit.php` file, you can see the entered values straight there on your screen - a helpful tool for debugging, allowing you to check that what you think was sent via POST was in fact sent, and that it was named and structured as you are expecting.
You can trivially populate the fields on the target form by retrieving and then echoing the passed data.

An example that will perform no error-checking, has no styling, is inert and that will populate two fields may look something like this:

**formsubmit.php**

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
?>
<html>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type='text' name='nameInput' value='<?php echo $name; ?>' />
    <input type='email' name='emailInput' value='<?php echo $email; ?>' />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```